# Multiple tabs on a page - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have the following code:  [Link](https://codepen.io/rparra12/pen/NJLaBe)

The problem is that the tabs are not active at the same time, when one is

active the other is disabled and I do not know how to make it work. I have

only used HTML and CSS

What I want is that both are active in tab 1 and that we keep active even

though we have the different tabs because my idea is to add more div with

tabs. I leave a link to CodePen and also insert the code here.

```css
.tabs {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.tabs label {
 order: 1; 
 display: block;
 padding: 1rem 2rem;
 cursor: pointer;
  background: #90CAF9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}
.tabs .tab {
  order: 99; 
  flex-grow: 1;
 width: 100%;
 display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
 display: none;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 background: #fff;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabone" checked="checked">
            <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
            <div class="tab">
              <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabtwo">
            <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
            <div class="tab">
              <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabthree">
            <label for="tabthree">Tab Three</label>
            <div class="tab">
              <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br><br><br>
          <div class="tabs">
                <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabfour" checked="checked">
                <label for="tabfour">Tab One</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabfive">
                <label for="tabfive">Tab Two</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabsix">
                <label for="tabsix">Tab Three</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
              <div class="tabs">
                <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabfour" checked="checked">
                <label for="tabfour">Tab One</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab One Content</h1>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabfive">
                <label for="tabfive">Tab Two</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab Two Content</h1>
                </div>
                <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabsix">
                <label for="tabsix">Tab Three</label>
                <div class="tab">
                  <h1>Tab Three Content</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
```

For the second section, add a different value to the `name` attribute for each set of radio buttons. What you were doing before was adding `checked` to two buttons in the same set of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the question, but it seems to me that you just need to use a different value for the `name` attribute in each separate tabset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to make many tab groups work (one is open others are close) independently from each other.

Add a different value of `name` attribute for each `set of tabs` such that each set will work as a unit where if one is opened other tabs would be closed.

In the example you have given, all the radios along the side of `tab` inside the first tab could have value of `name` attribute as `tab1` and other radios under second tab-group could have `tab2`.

PS: radio button's name attribute allows only one of same name radio buttons to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution working with two panels.

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.tabs label {
  order: 1; 
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #90CAF9;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs [class^="tab"] {
  order: 99; 
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + [class^="tab"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab One Content (1)</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab Two Content (1)</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tabthree">
    <label for="tabthree">Tab Three</label>
    <div class="tab">
        <h1>Tab Three Content (1)</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabfour" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabfour">Tab One</label>
    <div class="tab2">
        <h1>Tab One Content (2)</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabfive">
    <label for="tabfive">Tab Two</label>
    <div class="tab2">
        <h1>Tab Two Content (2)</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tab2" id="tabsix">
    <label for="tabsix">Tab Three</label>
    <div class="tab2">
        <h1>Tab Three Content (2)</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```